# super().__new__() for object vs type in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7, super, metaclass

Calling `super().__new__()` when overriding `__new__` in a metaclass contains the following function signature:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        clsobj = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, classdict)
```

However, when overriding `__new__` in a normal class, we have the following:

```
class A:

    def __new__(cls, *a, **kw):
        clsobj = super().__new__(cls)
```

Passing any other arguments to `super()` in `A.__new__` will lead to the following error:

```
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

I understand that in the second case, we are dealing with `object.__new__` while in the first case we are dealing with `type.__new__`.

My question is, why are these function signatures different? Why does `object.__new__` only accept `cls`?

Comment: Yes, the function signatures are different. Because `type.__new__` and `object.__new__` do different things. Although, perhaps the real question is, why doesn't `object.__new__` accept *any* parameters, e.g. `*args, **kwargs`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`object` and `type` have an interesting relationship. `object` is an instance of `type`, but `type` is a subclass of `object`.

`__new__`, however, focuses on the creation of an instance of a class, and so `object.__new__` is the lowest common denominator: it does virtually nothing on its own, because there is virtually nothing that instances of *every* possible class have in common. As such, `object.__new__` needs no more information than the type its return value will have.

`type.__new__` does quite a bit more than `object.__new__`: it has to create an object that itself is capable of creating new objects. This requires quite a bit more information, so `type.__new__` defines several additional parameters when it overrides `object.__new__`.

---

Note, however, that `type` itself does *not* use `super`; if you define two classes

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("In A.__new__")
        return super().__new__(cls)


class B(type, A):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct, *args, **kwargs):
        print("In B.__new__")
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
```

you'll see that `B("B", (), {})` outputs `In B.__new__` but not `In A.__new__`. `type.__new__` is the end of the line, so to speak, for creating metaclasses.

Typically, though, you wouldn't mix classes like this. Just like you rarely include `object` in the list of base classes for a class (I'm almost willing to say you *never* would), you don't often inherit from `type` and another (meta)class, and I can't think of any reason why you would try to inherit from both `type` and a non-type subclass of `object`.

Comment: Is this distinction expressed in the Python docs? I have been trying to discover it in the docs, but haven't been able to.

Comment: Not explicitly, as far as I am aware. But it's a logical consequence of the relationship outlined in the first sentence (which you can verify using `instanceof(object, type)` and `issubclass(type, object)`).